# Include message hash in Metadata using grpc-java on ClientInterceptor?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am using grpc-java for a PoC and one of the main objectives of this test is to validate Metadata/Message integrity; basically I am trying to hash some call properties (user, time, traceId, etc.) and the data sent to the server into a single JWT token that's sent as Metadata.

The problem I am facing is that using ClientInterceptor and SimpleForwardingClientCall the "sendMessage" method, from where I would get the message hash, is called after the "start" method where the Metadata is available... and it seems that by design Metadata is sent while executing the "start" method so I would have to calculate the hash of the data sent before that...

Has anyone done something like this? Am I missing some functionality?

Thanks for any help or advice...

Answer (score 1):

You can delay calling `next.newCall()` or calling `clientCall.start()` until your interceptor's `sendMessage()` is called. You would need to save the values in fields and then play them back when `sendMessage()` is called.

Comment: I did something like this, but I'm not sure if it could break under a non blocking call.  I'm still trying to fully understand the threading model of the library, and get a grasp of which thread run's what...

Comment: I don't know what what you mean by "break." The call and the call listener are not thread-safe. The call is used on whatever thread the application wants. The grpc library tends to call the listener on a set of threads.

Comment: My doubt here si that I am not sure if each call, `start` and `sendMessage`, are executed in sequence inside the same grpc thread, or if the library could choose to execute them in different threads and I should use Context's... if it's the first scenario, I could do with private instance and local variables, but if not, grcp could be instanciating a new listener for each method call. Going to the src of grpc should help, but I haven't had the time for that...

Comment: The application is in control of which thread is used when calling any methods on `ClientCall`, so it could be on any thread. gRPC uses the Context from `newCall()`; yes, that isn't documented. The only reasonable choices are `newCall()` and `start()`, and those are virtually always run from the same thread with same Context. You can save the context and restore it when calling newCall/start.

Comment: After talking about this in the forums (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/4684), it seems Metadata is not the option i'm looking for since in an streaming scenario, start is only called once for the whole steam, not for each message. I'll have to add a field to the message to send the JWT token